# WEKA linear regression error rate too high

Tags: excel, weka, linear-regression, data-analysis

I am trying to perform linear regression on a set of data i.e. books, and predict the ratings using all the attributes. Below is how i formatted my data on Excel then conveted the file to csv to upload it on WEKA

```
Book    Author  Genre   Publisher   Year    Rating
1   1   5   1   2008    5
1   1   5   1   2008    5
1   1   5   1   2008    5
1   1   5   1   2008    5
1   1   5   1   2008    5
1   1   5   1   2008    5
1   1   5   1   2008    5
1   1   5   1   2008    5
1   1   5   1   2008    5
1   1   5   1   2008    5
1   1   5   1   2008    5
1   1   5   1   2008    5
1   1   5   1   2008    5
1   1   5   1   2008    5
1   1   5   1   2008    5
1   1   5   1   2008    5
1   1   5   1   2008    5
1   1   5   1   2008    5
1   1   5   1   2008    5
1   1   5   1   2008    5
1   1   5   1   2008    5
1   1   5   1   2008    5
1   1   5   1   2008    5
```

I did this for  a list of 25 books, altogether i have 2431 instances. On WEKA i've converted the first four attributes from "NumericToNominal" then chose the fucntion "Linear Regression". This is my outcome:

```
Scheme:weka.classifiers.functions.LinearRegression -S 0 -R 1.0E-8
Relation:     Books WEKA-weka.filters.unsupervised.attribute.NumericToNominal-Rfirst-4
Instances:    2430
Attributes:   6
              Book
              Author
              Genre
              Publisher
              Year
              Rating
Test mode:10-fold cross-validation

=== Classifier model (full training set) ===


Linear Regression Model

Rating =

      0.2267 * Book=18,15,25,13,8,24,20,17,16,19,11,4,6,21,3,7,23,12,1,9,10,14,2 +
      0.4458 * Book=8,24,20,17,16,19,11,4,6,21,3,7,23,12,1,9,10,14,2 +
     -0.1527 * Book=24,20,17,16,19,11,4,6,21,3,7,23,12,1,9,10,14,2 +
     -0.314  * Book=20,17,16,19,11,4,6,21,3,7,23,12,1,9,10,14,2 +
      0.6751 * Book=19,11,4,6,21,3,7,23,12,1,9,10,14,2 +
      0.475  * Book=4,6,21,3,7,23,12,1,9,10,14,2 +
     -0.4018 * Book=3,7,23,12,1,9,10,14,2 +
      0.2522 * Book=7,23,12,1,9,10,14,2 +
     -0.4505 * Book=23,12,1,9,10,14,2 +
     -0.2583 * Book=12,1,9,10,14,2 +
      0.4949 * Book=10,14,2 +
     -0.3875 * Author=1,6,2,4,11,12,9,3,13,10,15 +
     -0.7318 * Author=6,2,4,11,12,9,3,13,10,15 +
      0.594  * Author=2,4,11,12,9,3,13,10,15 +
      0.379  * Author=4,11,12,9,3,13,10,15 +
      0.6818 * Author=11,12,9,3,13,10,15 +
      0.4396 * Author=12,9,3,13,10,15 +
      1.0057 * Author=9,3,13,10,15 +
     -1.4347 * Author=3,13,10,15 +
     -0.4547 * Author=13,10,15 +
      0.3638 * Author=10,15 +
     -0.4921 * Author=15 +
      0.2706 * Genre=7,5,2,1,6,4,8 +
     -0.4036 * Genre=5,2,1,6,4,8 +
     -0.7927 * Genre=2,1,6,4,8 +
     -0.4448 * Genre=1,6,4,8 +
      0.5731 * Genre=6,4,8 +
      0.5519 * Genre=8 +
      0.4517 * Publisher=21,9,8,2,20,10,3,22,5,11,1,18 +
     -0.4474 * Publisher=2,20,10,3,22,5,11,1,18 +
     -0.3018 * Publisher=10,3,22,5,11,1,18 +
      0.474  * Publisher=5,11,1,18 +
      0.6567 * Publisher=1,18 +
     -0.492  * Publisher=18 +
      3.5816

Time taken to build model: 0.28 seconds

=== Cross-validation ===
=== Summary ===

Correlation coefficient                  0.2415
Mean absolute error                      0.7883
Root mean squared error                  0.9772
Relative absolute error                 98.4114 %
Root relative squared error             97.0741 %
Total Number of Instances             2430
```

Instead of showing one calculation for each attribute, its showing multiple calculations and as you can see the error rate is quite high. Is there anything wrong with the way i've presented the data thats causing this issue?